# Create a Jquery animation like Flipboard popup 

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, popup, flipboard

I want to implement a Jquery/JS animation like the Flipboard popup animation.

When user clicks on an image, the image will expand to a certain size and its white background expands until it occupies the whole screen.

Once the animation is done the page content will be loaded.
http://flipboard.com/

Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm trying to use Jquery animations.

Comment: cool! You can do it with animations, show us how far you got.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted what code you have so far.

Comment: Ok I will post it later. I'm still attempting it with the Codrops example.

Answer (score 1):

[Codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/) did it a few months back, I can't really write out all the code for you here but give [this article](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/05/07/experimental-page-layout-inspired-by-flipboard/) a read.

Comment: Hi Thanks! I already tried it, but I could not find any documentation or code level details to implement it. Do you have any other resources..?

Comment: Download the source at the bottom of the codrops article and open the files. There's a folder called js and inside it a file call flips.js, this is where most of the functionality is... but it's about 1000 lines of code so you should have a reasonable understanding of Javascript before you launch into it

Comment: Thanks I'm referring it to now.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
```

//Finally I found the answer. This is the full code.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('.box').click(function(e){

        if( $('div').hasClass('overlay')==false ){

        //event.preventDefault();
        var $box = $(this);

        $('<div class="overlay"></div>').prependTo($box);

        var $overlay = $('.overlay');

        $overlay.css( {
                       'position'       : 'absolute',
                       'background-color'   : 'white',
                       'width'              : $box.outerWidth(true),
                       'height'     : $box.outerHeight(true),
                       'left'       : $box.offset().left,
                       'top'        : $box.offset().top,
                       'z-index'        : 99999999
        });                                       
        //$($placeholder).insertAfter('.box');  

        $overlay.animate({
                width: $(document).width(),
                height: $(document).height(),
                left: '0px',
                top: '0px'
            }, 500, function() {
                //reset the overlay
                $overlay.css({'width': ''});
                $overlay.css({'height': '1500px'});
                //ajax    
                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "../ajax/get_event.php",  
                    data: "firstname=clint&lastname=eastwood",  
                    success: function(resp){  
                        // we have the response  
                        $overlay.html(resp);
                        $('.window').fadeIn(200);
                    },  
                    error: function(e){  
                        alert('Error: ' + e);  
                    }  
                });
        });

        }else{
            //click only on overlay to exit
            var $target = $(e.target);    
            if ( $target.is('.overlay') ) {
               $('.overlay').remove();
            }
        }  

    });//end box click

});//end of jquery
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Codrops have just posted [a plugin to do this, and instructions on how to use it.](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/09/03/bookblock-a-content-flip-plugin/) Theres a particularly cool demo of the plugin [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/BookBlock/index3.html).